# Push ViewController very slow

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delay, pushviewcontroller

I would like to push `UIViewController` from another `UIViewController`. I just sending few JSON results to the recipient controller like below:.

```
SSCheckoutController *shopController=[[SSCheckoutController alloc]init];
shopController.checkoutInfo = checkOutNeed;
shopController.discountJson = discPgmDetails;
shopController.IsPaymentMethod = @"CREDITCARD";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:shopController animated:YES];
```

But it is taking more than 30 seconds. There is also no operation running in background, but still why is just a push taking so much time? Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: In the `SSCheckoutController` class, are you performing any heavy lifting in `init`, `loadView`, `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: Yes i did , Not I made that as asyc calls. It solved my issue :)